# Testing javascript via cucumber--is there a non-jruby solution?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber

Currently we're using Cucumber, Capybara, Celerity/Culerity w/jruby and I'm frustrated by the spurious failures on our Ajax and javascript heavy app. Not only that buy on our VM we end up having segmentation faults and memory issues after running the test suite about 5 times (we run it nightly and after every svn commit). I'd like to exorcise java from the loop if possible to at least narrow down the possible points of failure. Is there a good solution for these integration tests that doesn't end up going through jruby?

Or does anyone else have any other ideas about which way to go? I love cucumber as a tool but the whole setup for us has an awful signal to noise ratio and I end up managing test run output fairly often (every morning :p).

thanks

Comment: What part of this is forcing you to use jruby?

Comment: culerity and celerity wrap HtmlUnit, which is implemented in java I *think*. I inherited this setup and am tired of evaluating all these spurious failures daily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heavy-weight but quite bulletproof - [selenium](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara) (see drivers section). Also you can take a look into a quite new and more lightweight and fast alternative - [capybara-webkit](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit)

Comment: I think I'm heading toward capybara-webkit. suggestion was in this answer first, but both answers are deeply appreciated...

Comment: Points are secondary to useful content and the warm, fuzzy feeling which comes from helping another poor fool. (I'm a poor fool.)

Answer (score 1):

Presently (as we speak, really) I'm using rspec, capybara and capybara-webkit.

Installing and using capybara-webkit is very simple (just be sure to follow the instructions here: https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit). I have found that inside a test I need to declare the need for javascript (:js => true).

```
describe "After a client user creates a ticket" do  
  it "the page should have a browse button for file upload", :js => true do    
    call_to_helper_method  
    page.has_button?('sparkly_button_name')  
  end
end
```

As easy as that!

Comment: I should admit that I didn't truly address your cucumber-specific question, we recently tasked ourselves with black box testing and decided on that combination of gems.

Comment: Sadly I have to fit this into the cucumber world. Still might be able to use those gems somehow. We have several hundred ATs already in cucumber and the last thing I want to do is setup another hudson build and monitor THAT as well. thanks for the information...

Comment: you can easily run cucumber features using capybara webkit.

Comment: @jaydel: looks like this guy's doing it, perhaps this article will help. http://blog.thefrontiergroup.com.au/2011/08/guest-series-peter-cooper-capybara-webkit-bringing-webkit-to-your-integration-tests/